# Whatsapp Web in Android Studio WebView

Tags: android-studio, webview

I'm trying to use Android Studio WebView to open Whatsapp Web in Desktop mode on my phone, but although other websites that I use are loading, Whatsapp Web isn't.

That's my code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.whatsappweb

import android.app.Activity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        WAwebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.84")
        WAwebView.webViewClient = WebClient(this)
        WAwebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        WAwebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        WAwebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(LOAD_NO_CACHE)
        WAwebView.reload()
        WAwebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true)
        WAwebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)
        WAwebView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com")    
    }
}

class WebClient internal constructor(private val activity: Activity):WebViewClient(){
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
        return true
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WAwebView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.julenny.whatsappweb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea why the Whatsapp Web isn't loading? I know that the user-agent I'm using is indeed identical to the one I'm using in my browser on my Windows PC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem...

the weird part is that if I set the user agent, it works only on the first run... once I close the app and open it again it doesn't work anymore... and I can't clear the data stored, because I want for the user to stay logged...

**Update**: I found a solution for my problem...

**Set the user agent after you load the page**

Instead of doing:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("ur user agent");
webView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

Do:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("ur user agent");
```